# how to know about designed airways above my house

Tags: airways

Newbie here.
I hear quite a lot airplanes and helicopters and all kind of weird flying things above my head, at least one every 2 or 3 minutes, so I started tracking them with ADS-B.
There's a commercial airport in the region (MXP), not extremely close, but it seems that my house sits on some kind of airway (? not sure about the correct word) because everything leaving and approaching that airport to/from east just passes over my head making a lot of noise and I do not notice the same thing when driving nearby.
So my question is: is there a publicly available information about these routes? Are they static? I tried to check skyvector but I can't understand those.
Is there some kind of altitude limitation flights must comply? Just for fun, I'd like to compare those with ADS-B received data.

Edit: screenshot attached, on the left there's the airport, on the right two planes and an helicopter that just passed above my head.
Highlighted one is almost above my house.
[image: planes taking off]

Comment: Do you by any chance live directly north or south of the airport?

Comment: I am actually almost east, but the planes takeoff in north direction, then they turn back, let's see if I can attach a screenshot

Comment: When the wind is from the north airplanes will take off towards the north, if their destination is to the south or east they will be vectored in that direction.

Answer (score 4):

Airways is a term that is used for the sort of "highways in the sky" that a lot of commercial air traffic use.

However, as you are reasonably close to an airport what you're most likely referring to is SIDS (Standard instrument departures) or STARS (Standard terminal arrivals). Both of these can be found quite easily by searching for the airport name/identifier along with those 2 terms

One such example is here: https://v1aviation.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/LIMC.pdf

It is a long document with a lot of information, however around page 19 you start to see some example departure routes from one of the northerly runways, which do indeed turn east and west depending on the route the aircraft is taking. You might recognise some of the local topography and be able to estimate where your house is based on local knowledge.

Edited to add: The screenshot you have added looks similar to the easterly departure from 35L.

[image]

However, as pointed out in comments, the actual departure of that flight was from 35R, so the SID followed is likely to be the one later on in the linked PDF (pp 23-onwards).

Comment: Really interesting!
Is there in these maps also something related to altitude?

Comment: @vitom The underlined numbers on that SID are the *not below* altitudes at each point.

Comment: I disagree that the procedure shown in the screenshot of the answer is the same as the one in the question. the flight took off from 35R https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/az1019#21296241
the procedure followed is at page 20/23 of the pdf, through MC602/MC607

Comment: @Federico thanks, answer updated. I shouldn't have been so sure without checking the flight details.

Comment: np. personally I would change the image, but I leave the decision to you.

Comment: @Jamiec For altitudes on a SID/STAR, a line below means "not below", a line above means "not above", and both means "exactly".

Comment: @StephenS thanks. That was somewhere in the depths of my memory. But I wasnt 100% sure.

Comment: @StephenS even more interesting! I assume these are feet? I rarely see a plane above 4000m after the turn, in either 17R / 35R paths

Comment: @vitom Yes, aviation uses nautical units (feet, knots, etc.) unless otherwise specified.